# Rails - ActiveAdmin & CanCan custom override method for initialize_cancan_ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancan, cancancan

I am attempting to pass thru request data to the Ability model as suggested here:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  #...

  private

  def current_ability
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user, request.remote_ip)
  end
end
```

and here:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user, ip_address=nil)
    can :create, Comment unless BLACKLIST_IPS.include? ip_address
  end
end
```

See: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Accessing-request-data

However, I am using ActiveAdmin with the CancanAdapter, and it uses a separate initialize call via:

```
def initialize_cancan_ability
  klass = resource.namespace.cancan_ability_class
  klass = klass.constantize if klass.is_a? String
  klass.new user
end
```

See: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/cancan_adapter.rb

So how/where can I redefine `initialize_cancan_ability` so that I can pass in request data similar to the `current_ability` example?

Basically I'm hoping to just replace the last line as such:

`klass.new user, request`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a file under `lib/monkey_patches/active_admin.rb` and put your overridden method there:

```
require 'cancan'

# Add a setting to the application to configure the ability
ActiveAdmin::Application.inheritable_setting :cancan_ability_class, "Ability"

module ActiveAdmin
    private

    def initialize_cancan_ability
      klass = resource.namespace.cancan_ability_class
      klass = klass.constantize if klass.is_a? String
      klass.new user, request
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves the main issue, but unfortunately the `request` object is not available to the method.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Devise, you can access the the Ip from the User model `user.current_sign_in_ip`